# MySQL: Undesired result with max function on a timestamp

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, aggregate-functions, mantis

I use a Mantis Bug Database (that uses MySQL) and I want to query which bugs had a change in their severity within the last 2 weeks, however only the last severity change of the bug should be indicated.

The problem is, that I get multiple entries per bugID (which is the primary key), which is not my desired result since I want to have only the latest change per bug. This means that somehow I am using the max function and the group by clause wrongfully.

Here you can see my query:

```
SELECT `bug_id`,
    max(date_format(from_unixtime(`mantis_bug_history_table`.`date_modified`),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')) AS `Severity_changed`,
    `mantis_bug_history_table`.`old_value`,
    `mantis_bug_history_table`.`new_value`
    from `prepared_bug_list` 
    join `mantis_bug_history_table` on `prepared_bug_list`.`bug_id` = `mantis_bug_history_table`.`bug_id` 
    where (`mantis_bug_history_table`.`field_name` like 'severity') 
    group by `bug_id`,`old_value`,`.`new_value`
    having (`Severity_modified` >= (now() - interval 2 week))
    order by bug_id` ASC
```

For the bug with the id 8 for example I get three entries with this query. The bug with the id 8 had indeed three severity changes within the last 2 weeks but I only want to get the latest severity change.

What could be the problem with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have a solution! I friend of mine helped me and one part of the solution was to include the Primary key of the mantis bug history table, which is not the bug_id, but the column id, which is a consecutive number.
Another part of the solution was the subquery in the where clause:

```
    select `prepared_bug_list`.`bug_id` AS `bug_id`,
`mantis_bug_history_table`.`old_value` AS `old_value`,
`mantis_bug_history_table`.`new_value` AS `new_value`,
`mantis_bug_history_table`.`type` AS `type`,
date_format(from_unixtime(`mantis_bug_history_table`.`date_modified`),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS `date_modified`
 FROM `prepared_bug_list`
 JOIN mantis_import.mantis_bug_history_table
 ON `prepared_bug_list`.`bug_id` = mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id
 where (mantis_bug_history_table.id = -- id = that is the id of every history entry, not confuse with bug_id
    (select `mantis_bug_history_table`.`id` from `mantis_bug_history_table` 
     where ((`mantis_bug_history_table`.`field_name` = 'severity') 
     and (`mantis_bug_history_table`.`bug_id` = `prepared_bug_list`.`bug_id`))
    order by `mantis_bug_history_table`.`date_modified` desc limit 1)
and `date_modified` > unix_timestamp() - 14*24*3600 ) 
order by `prepared_bug_list`.`bug_id`,`mantis_bug_history_table`.`date_modified` desc
```

Answer (score 1):

`max()` is an aggregation function and it does not appear to be suitable for what you are trying to do.

I have feeling that what you are trying to do is to get the latest out of all the applicable bug_id in `mantis_bug_history_table` .  If that is true, then I would rewrite the query as the following -- I would write a sub-query `getLatest` and join it with `prepared_bug_list`

**Updated answer**

**Caution: I don't have access to the actual DB tables so this query may have bugs**

```
select
    `getLatest`.`last_bug_id`
    , `mantis_bug_history_table`.`date_modified`
    , `mantis_bug_history_table`.`old_value`
    , `mantis_bug_history_table`.`new_value`
from 
    (
        select
              (
                select
                    `bug_id` 
                from
                    `mantis_bug_history_table` 
                where 
                    `date_modified` > unix_timestamp() - 14*24*3600 -- two weeks
                    and `field_name` like 'severity'
                    and `bug_id` = `prepared_bug_list`.`bug_id`
                order by 
                    `date_modified` desc
                limit 1
              ) as `last_bug_id`
        from
            `prepared_bug_list` 
    ) as `getLatest`
    inner join `mantis_bug_history_table`
            on `prepared_bug_list`.`bug_id` = `getLatest`.`last_bug_id`     
order by `getLatest`.`bug_id` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer however I do not understand how the joined subquery (getLatest) will help. Limit 1 says that I will get only one row in total for the whole query (which is then only one bug for which I see results). I think your intention with the subquery was to get the latest result per each bug with sorting the date in descending order (which puts the latest at the top) and the limit it with 1 result per bug but it does not work as you have intended.

Comment: @Bruder -- I don't have access to your DB so I cannot debug my query other than just eye-balling it.  You can troubleshoot by just taking out the sub-query and see what it get.  Perhaps in your data there were indeed only one bug in the last two weeks?  Good luck! (Or you can put your data and table on SqlFiddle.com and I can further debug my query.)

Comment: Not, there are multiple entries for multiple bugs in the last 2 weeks.
But for all those bugs I wanted to get the latest entry for each bug.
The subquery as you have suggested it does not work in my case.

Comment: @Bruder -- I am sorry.  Indeed I had a bug in the logic of my last query.  It seems like we cannot avoid to use a **correlated subquery** (which tends to be slow).  I have updated my answer.  Please see if it works and let me know.

Comment: I tried your edited query but it does not work. The on-clause btw cannot work because prepared_bug_list is neither joined or in the from clause (it is in the in the subqueries but the engine wants to see it in the top layer if it is used in the on-clause.

Also, the order-by statement does not work as bug_id is not a column of getLatest. 

I am sorry but I have to try something else.

Comment: @Bruder -- I am sorry to hear that my updated query did not work.  If you put your table schema (and hopefully some test data too) on SqlFiddle.com, I am happy to try again.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, your hint with the limit 1 was the right path. I have now a solution; i have posted it below.